# Xcode - unicode character MD not appearing in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, unicode

Here is a photo of whats happening:

[image]

The simulator is showing a question mark for my unicode string. I changed to different fonts but its the same thing.  The unicode im trying to show is a raised MD. You can see [here](https://codepoints.net/U+1F16B).  this is the french registered trademark symbol.  The string is read from a localizedable.strings file and its reading the data successful its just not rendering the unicode part. Here is the string:

```
"login_label" ="\U1F16B Carte Platine MasterCard"
```

update: one way i went about this is to add M and D separate:

```
\u1d39\u1d30
```

but that did not make it a supscript.  then instead I made it html:

```
NSString * htmlString = @"<html><body> Some html string <sup>MD</sup></body></html>";
NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

_label.attributedText = attrStr;
```

Comment: I don't see that character on my machine even through your linked page)

Comment: That characters seems not to be available, the cold points skip from \U1F169 to \U1F170. But if what you want is a French copyright symbol you might look for one in plane 0 or a surrogate pair.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add the French trademark symbol (MD)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960218/how-can-i-add-the-french-trademark-symbol-md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that as of this date the unicode point \U1F16B is not supported by Mac OS.

I can not find that character in the Character Viewer and it the glyph does not render in the [WikiBooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/1F000-1FFFF) page.

The Chartacter Viewer skips from the cold points skips from \U1F169 to \U1F170.

See this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960218/how-can-i-add-the-french-trademark-symbol-md) "How can I add the French trademark symbol (MD)?"