# How to add Superscript string in Localization file in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, localization, ios11.4

I have localizable English and French. I want display Registered symbols as a part of word i.e "MyApp®". English part of localization file shows this symbol correct in iOS APP UI. Same needs to display for French version i.e "MyAppᴹᴰ" but space comes in between 'M' and 'D'.

I also tried using unicode like `MyApp\u{1D39}\u{1D30}`. This gets worked in Swift playground but if I try it through Localization file it doesn't work.

iOS version: 11.4
I need to make changes in localization file only and not to use NSAttributed string every where in code.
If anyone came across same problem, and found solution please post.

```
"MyApp®" = "MyApp\u{1D39}\u{1D30}" // Localization file

print(String(describing: "MyApp\u{1D39}\u{1D30}" // swift playground
print(String(describing: "ᴹᴰ")) // swift playground

"MyApp®" = "MyApp\u{1D39}\u{1D30}" // Localization file
"MyApp®" = "MyAppᴹᴰ" // Localization file- on UI space comes b/w ᴹ and ᴰ

print(String(describing: "MyApp\u{1D39}\u{1D30}")) // swift playground
print(String(describing: "ᴹᴰ")) // swift playground

"MyApp®" = "MyApp\u{1D39}\u{1D30}" // Localization file
```

On iOS app UI component should render MyApp® as MyAppᴹᴰ and no space between ᴹ and ᴰ.

Comment: Go through this link , may be it will help you >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960218/how-can-i-add-the-french-trademark-symbol-md

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the separate superscript `ᴹ` and `ᴰ` characters, why not use the actual  (U+1F16B) character?

In your localization file, put:

```
"MyApp®" = "MyApp"
```

Comment: I am using same  without space. Also would like add one more thing, on iOS 12 it works fine but below iOS 12 it shows "?" instead of .

Comment: You need to update your question to make it clear that you already know about the ` ` but that it doesn't work under iOS 11. Your question makes no mention of ` `, only the two separate characters. Most likely it is a newer Unicode character only added since iOS 12.